# Request method 'POST' not supported when calling birt report

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, birt

I'm trying to call Birt report from a controller as following :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/birtReport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiOperation("Download Report")
public void birtReport(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ErrorExceptions, IOException{
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet postRequest = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/birt/run?__report=MyFirstReport.rptdesign&id=211");
        HttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        InputStream body = response1.getEntity().getContent();
        IOUtils.copy(body, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();

    }
```

but i'm getting the following error :

```
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

> Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:374)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:314)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:940)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

any idea how to fix it ?

Thank you in advance.

After inspecting the page generated in chrome the error is as the following :

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/statReport/birtReport__sessionId=20180313_115522_490?__sessionId=20180313_115522_490&__dpi=96
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Comment: How are you calling your controller ?

Comment: @Berger http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/statReport/birtReport

Comment: @Berger i've edited the question above please check the last part if you can help,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change

```
HttpGet postRequest = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/birt/run?__report=MyFirstReport.rptdesign&id=211");
```

To

```
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/birt/run?__report=MyFirstReport.rptdesign&id=211");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the method to `RequestMethod.POST`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/birtReport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score 0):

See web.xml if it is configured like this.
if /* It causes post to no be unparsed .

```
<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```